# iOS Page sheet & Form sheet

Tags: ios, user-interface

According to iOS Human Interface Guidelines, a modal view can be in the form of a page sheet or form sheet, among others.

Page sheet is described as: Partially covers the underlying content on larger devices held in landscape orientation. All uncovered areas are dimmed to prevent interaction with them. Covers the entire screen on smaller devices and in portrait orientation.

And Form sheet as:  Appears centered on screen, but may be repositioned if a keyboard is visible. All uncovered areas are dimmed to prevent interaction with them. May cover the entire screen on smaller devices.

What is the real difference in the look of these 2 forms?

I couldn't find the description of Form sheet in the developer docs. Only the page sheet (https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle/1621358-pagesheet).

Can someone be so kind to explain, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 32):

You likely have found the answer to this by now, but I wanted to make sure this question has an answer for everyone else who stumbles upon it.

### Page Sheet

On regular-width, regular-height size class devices such as iPad, Page Sheet covers almost all vertical distance but does not go all the way to the top. Horizontally, space is left on both sides. An example of this is Apple's Mail application when composing a new email. Here's a simple screenshot from the simulator:

[image: Page Sheet Demo]

### Form Sheet

A Form Sheet is similar to a Page Sheet except that it leaves even more space on each side and also leaves more space on both the top and bottom. The effect is basically a floating box:

[image: Form Sheet Demo]

Comment: Just compared the two myself. In my case, the page sheet filled the whole iPad's screen (excluding the status bar, which may be dependent on `edgesForExtendedLayout` configuration), while the form sheet looked more like yours (imposing a default preferred content size). I wonder why the behaviour between ours is different.

Comment: @JamieBirch Were you in portrait orientation? I believe filling the screen may be expected for Page Sheet in Portrait since there's less space.

Comment: I am trying this on an iPhone 7 Plus Landscape (height: regular). Both display with space on the top, left and right and none on the bottom. The form sheet does not have rounded corners on the bottom but the page sheet does. This seems very weird. Would you know an explanation for this?